# Add items in nested dictionary

Tags: python, nested

I'm teaching myself Python and I'm trying to create an ordering application in Python. The program adds user-given product numbers and their prices to a new dictionary.

But I can't figure out a way for the prices of the items to be added together.

```
alijst = {}
kera = {1001 : {"naam" : '60 X 60 Lokeren', 'prijs' : 31.95},#the third item (31.95) is the prize and needs to be used in a calculation later
          1002 : {"naam" : '40 X 80 Houtlook' , 'prijs' : 32.5},
          1003 : {"naam" : '60 X 60 Beïge', 'prijs' :  29.95}}

# The below is for finding the code linked to a product
def keramisch():
    global kera
    global alijst
    klaar = False
    while klaar != True:
        product = int(input("type a product code or press 0 to close: "))
        if product in kera:
            alijst[product] = kera[product]
        else:
            if product == 0:
                klaar = True
# The below is what I tried for calculation (it sucks)
def berekenprijs():
    global alijst
    global prijslijst
    for i, prijs in alijst:
        print(i)
        aantal = int(input("give an amount"))
        totaalprijs = aantal * prijs
        prijslijst[totaalprijs]
watbestellen()
berekenprijs()
```

How do I get the price into the last def?

Comment: I believe @Thomas Weller has given the correct answer below. I will just add a comment to point out that using `global alijst` like this is considered bad practice. It's possible for your functions to take arguments, which (among other reasons) is better than using `global`s because it allows your functions to be re-used.

Comment: Do note that your question will be more useful to a larger part of the international audience of Stack Overflow if you use English names for your variables.

Answer (score 5):

I think your mistake is here:

```
for i, prijs in alijst:
```

This will give you the order code (`i`) and the product, not the price. The product then has a list of properties, one of them is "naam", the other is "prijs".

Also note that you need `.items()` to iterate over key and value.

```
for i, prijs in alijst.items():
```

So, to access the product name, you would need to write

```
print(prijs["naam"])
```

and to access the price, you would need

```
print(prijs["prijs"])
```

The latter makes it obvious that the naming goes wrong here.

Therefore I suggest to rename those variables to

```
for productcode, product in alijst.items():
```

and then access the properties of the product with

```
print(product["naam"])
print(product["prijs"])
```

There are still some issues left, which I'll leave for you practising, e.g.

- `global prijslijst` refers to a variable that is not defined
- `watbestellen()` is not defined. Likely you meant `keramisch()` instead
- `prijslijst[totaalprijs]` does nothing, but since `prijslijst` is missing, I can hardly figure out what you wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

I tried to keep to your code as much as possible but reorganized it where I thought it made it cleaner.

Note: globals are discouraged except for special purposes such coding games and not needed in this case.

```
def keramisch():
  " Gets product code and verifies that it exists in kera "
  while True:
    product = input('Product code or blank line to close: ')
    if not product:
      return None # blank line entered
    elif product.isnumeric():
      product = int(product)  # covert string to int
      if product in kera:
        return product
      else:
        print('Product code does not exist')
    else:
      print('Product code should be numeric, or blank line to close.')

def berekenprijs():
  " Gets list of products and caculates total "
  alijst = {}
  while True:
    # Get product
    product = keramisch()
    if product is None:
      break

    while True:
      # Get Amount
      aantal = input('Amount of product: ')
      if not aantal.isnumeric():
        print('Amount should be numeric')
      else:
        alijst[product] = int(aantal)
        break  # done with entering amount

  # Calculate total
  total = 0
  for product in alijst:
    price = kera[product]['prijs']
    quantity = alijst[product]

    total += quantity*price  # quantity x price

  print(f'Total Price is: {total}')

kera = {1001 : {"naam" : '60 X 60 Lokeren', 'prijs' : 31.95},#the third item (31.95) is the prize and needs to be used in a calculation later
          1002 : {"naam" : '40 X 80 Houtlook' , 'prijs' : 32.5},
          1003 : {"naam" : '60 X 60 Beïge', 'prijs' :  29.95}}

# Usage
berekenprijs()
```